# Save the result of a function separately for each time it's called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm very much a beginner in JavaScript so there's probably a simple way of doing what I want, but I don't know it.

I have a function which takes the input from a few sliders, does some calculations on them and spits the result out in a variable. The function returns the value of this variable, so something like that:

```
fun() {
slider1=parseFloat($('#field1').val());
    //some calculations here
slider2=parseFloat($('#field1').val());
    //some calculations here

totalsum=(slider1+slider2);
    return totalsum;
}
```

The function is bound `onClick` on a button. What I want to do is to save the result of the function in a different variable for each time the button is pressed. So if you move the sliders and press the button, the result is stored in `totalsum`, then you can change the sliders and press the button again, and that result would be saved in `totalsum2`, and so on.

I hope that makes sense, let me know if it doesn't and I'll try to explain it again.

Comment: Rather than storing the result in new variable, just push it to an array.

Comment: `#field1` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating different variables. **Create an array** and use `push()`

```
const totalsums = [];
function fun() {
    let slider1=parseFloat($('#field1').val());
    //some calculations here
    let slider2=parseFloat($('#field1').val());
    //some calculations here

    let totalsum=(slider1+slider2);
    totalsums.push(totalsum)
}
```

Comment: Maheer, why the `let slider1` and `let totalsums = [];` instead of `const`?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Nice suggestion. `const` is better

Comment: Thanks. that was simple enough. I'll just ask a follow-up question here instead of opening a new thread. Is there something that I can add to the function which changes the behavior of the button (hides it) after the array has reached 20 elements? I.e. I don't want people to be able to press it more than 20 times.

Comment: Use this line `if(totalsums.length === 20) $('button').hide()`.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan did you downvoted the answer. If yes please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.sums = []

input.onclick = () => {
  const slider1=+$('#field1').val();
    //some calculations here
  const slider2=+$('#field1').val();
    //some calculations here

  const totalsum= slider1 + slider2;
  
  window.sums.push(totalsum)
  
  return totalsum;
}
```

Comment: Alex, assuming you know the difference in JavaScript between the unary `+` (as value prefix) and `parseFloat()`, care to explain why you think `+` should be used?

Comment: He gets value from jquery slider, i consider its normal to use unary `+` here due to normalized values